# Not able to communicate between android and webserver

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, android-studio

It is always giving Incorrect credentials, I have double checked the database ,Is there some issue with the code . I am new to android studio,
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

MainActivity

```
    package com.tarun.proxy_maar;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

    String username;
    String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view){
        username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

        login(username,password);

    }

    private void login(final String username, String password) {

        class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            private Dialog loadingDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uname = params[0];
                String pass = params[1];

                InputStream is = null;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
                String result = null;

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://shaadi.web44.net/hello.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                String s = result.trim();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                    intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
        la.execute(username, password);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

PHP SCRIPT ON WEBSERVER

```
<?php
define('HOST','host');
define('USER','user');
define('PASS','password');
define('DB','database');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$sql = "select * from login where username='$username' and password='$password'";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($check)){
echo 'success';
}else{
echo 'failure';
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Logcat

```
10-11 07:57:42.852  28481-28481/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-11 07:57:42.852  28481-28481/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
10-11 07:57:42.856  28481-28481/? I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
10-11 07:57:42.897  28481-28488/? E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
10-11 07:57:42.897  28481-28488/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
10-11 07:57:42.900  28481-28481/? W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.tarun.proxy_maar-2/lib/x86
10-11 07:57:43.079  28481-28504/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-11 07:57:43.082  28481-28481/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabe7d170, tid 28481
10-11 07:57:43.135  28481-28504/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabe7d480, tid 28504
10-11 07:57:43.141  28481-28504/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-11 07:57:43.311  28481-28504/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-11 07:57:43.311  28481-28504/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7918a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-11 07:58:56.273  28481-28504/com.tarun.proxy_maar W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-11 07:58:56.274  28481-28504/com.tarun.proxy_maar W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7bf200, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-11 07:58:56.939  28481-28504/com.tarun.proxy_maar E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab815a40
10-11 07:58:57.128  28481-28504/com.tarun.proxy_maar W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-11 07:58:57.128  28481-28504/com.tarun.proxy_maar W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2e1e6c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-11 07:59:00.474  28481-28504/com.tarun.proxy_maar E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab8159d0
```

Comment: Here's some help: [How To Debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What does logcat show ?

Comment: @Pedro Lobito added logcat file

Comment: Nothing wrong on the logcat, what's the problem ?

Comment: Try the login on the server without android and see if it works.

Comment: @PedroLobito yes, it works when I tried without android

Answer (score 0):

I use the [jsoup library](http://jsoup.org/packages/jsoup-1.8.3.jar) to `post` data from my `android` apps and it's way easier, where's an example

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://shaadi.web44.net/hello.php")
              .data("username", uname)
              .data("password", pass)
              .userAgent("some user agent..or not...")
              .timeout(30000)
              .post();

String httpresponse = doc.text();
```